# Filtering the list return from apex method and display in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, filters

What I'm trying to do is to filter the results that return from a apex method.
I had a custom object named Customer with custom fields: Type and Name. So I used the following apex method to do the query.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Customer__c> getCustomer(Id recordId){
   return [
      SELECT Id, Type__c, Name__c
      FROM Customer__c
      WHERE Id = :recordId
   ];
}
```

It works fine and I can get the results. But the next step is to display the records in the accordions based on their `Type__c`, like the following

- Type-1

  - Customer A
  - Customer B
- Type-2

  - Customer C

So I tried the following JS + HTML to filter out the the data based on the `Type__c`.

```
<lightning-accordion>
   <lightning-accordion-section label="Type-1">
      <template for:each={t1data} for:item="item>
         <p key={item.Id}>{item.Name__c}</p>
      </template>
   </lightning-accordion-section>
   <lightning-accordion-section label="Type-2">
      <template for:each={t2data} for:item="item>
         <p key={item.Id}>{item.Name__c}</p>
      </template>
   </lightning-accordion-section>
<lightning-accordion>
```

```
@api recordId;

@wire(getCustomer, { recordId: '$recordId' })
records;

get t1data() {
   return this.records.data.filter(item => item.Type__c === 'Type 1');
}

get t2data() {
   return this.records.data.filter(item => item.Type__c === 'Type 2');
}
```

But no luck, the code did not work. So is there any solutions for this requirement or other workaround solution? I know that adding a `WHRER` clause in the SOQL but I am trying to avoid that. Please help. Also please explain more as I really want to know the tricks.

Answer (score 2):

Please, take a look at your SOQL query. You are filtering recordі by `Id`, so you will always get a single record (or exception if no such record with this `Id`)

In order to group elements of the array by some property you can use js with reduce function:

**LWC.js**

```
....
getGroupedByProperty(data, key){
    return data.reduce(function(storage, item) {
        let group = item[key];
        storage[group] = storage[group] || [];
        storage[group].push(item);
        return storage; 
    }, {}); 
}
....
```

Credits to [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I wasn't realizing that my SOQL got this error. I will look into your methods.